# Is the global namespace prefix only required for classes?

Tags: php, namespaces

I'm trying to figure out how namespaces work in PHP but have a hard time understanding when a global namespace prefix is required. Take the following example:

index.php

```
namespace MySpace;

require_once 'file.php';

Test::hello();

hi();
```

file.php

```
class Test {
    public static function hello () {
        echo 'hello';
    }
}

function hi() {
    echo 'hi';
}
```

This won't work but writing \Test::hello() instead will and echoes both "hello" and "hi".

Why isn't the \ required for hi() as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.fallback.php
>
> ## Using namespaces: fallback to global function/constant
>
> Inside a namespace, when PHP encounters an unqualified Name in a class
>   name, function or constant context, it resolves these with different
>   priorities. **Class names always resolve to the current namespace name.**
>   Thus to access internal or non-namespaced user classes, one must refer
>   to them with their fully qualified Name [...]
>
> **For functions and constants, PHP will fall back to global functions or
>   constants** if a namespaces function or constant does not exist.